# Unslider image problems

Tags: html, css, jquery-plugins

I'm using Unslider to show photos on the home page of a website I'm creating, but the images are surrounded by what looks to be padding - and there is no padding in my css. How can I fix this? It's making my clean gallery look awful.

Unslider plugin found here: http://unslider.com

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="banner">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="media/duo.jpg" alt="Duo"/></li>
        <li><img src="media/lastshot.jpg" alt="Last"/></li>
        <li><img src="media/rose.jpg" alt="rose"/></li>
        <li><img src="media/r0se.jpg" alt="D"/></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.banner {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
overflow: auto;

font-size: 18px;
line-height: 24px;
text-align: center;

color: #FFFFFF;
text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.05), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
background: #000000;
box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
}

 banner ul {
    list-style: none;
    width: 300%;
}
.banner ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
    min-height: 350px;

    -o-background-size: 100% 100%;
    -ms-background-size: 100% 100%;
    -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
    -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-size: 100% 100%;

    box-shadow: inset 0 -3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}
```

And here's a screenshot of what I'm talking about:
[image]

Comment: Can you put those in a fiddle or show your live website link?

Answer (score 2):

`<ul>` elements come with default padding value. I had the same problem. I solved it by adding `padding:0px` to the `.banner ul` style.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Images have a default padding value, add padding:0px; to the css file to ".banner ul li" and ".banner ul li img"